# "Unexpected token :" error using jQuery with the Shopify ajax api

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify, liquid

> Error

When making a call to the shopify ajax api I am getting an error shown in the developer tools console.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Clicking on this error in the javascript console oddly shows the response which is valid JSON:

```
{
"id":19728251846714,
"properties":null,
"quantity":1,
"variant_id":19728251846714,
"key":"19728251846714:f1a55a69aed71e7c10ca53fd3549edda",
"title":"Ritual Petalos de rosas y vino tinto - Obispado",
"price":139900,
"original_price":139900,
"discounted_price":139900,
"line_price":139900,
"original_line_price":139900,
"total_discount":0,
"discounts":[],
"sku":"",
"grams":0,
"vendor":"Casa Azul Spa",
"taxable":false,
"product_id":1959512244282,
"gift_card":false,
"url":"\/products\/ritual-petalos-de-rosas-y-vino-tinto?variant=19728251846714",
"image":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0087\/2267\/7818\/products\/PETALOS_DE_ROSAS_Y_VINO_TINTO.jpg?v=1538589224",
"handle":"ritual-petalos-de-rosas-y-vino-tinto",
"requires_shipping":false,
"product_type":"",
"product_title":"Ritual Petalos de rosas y vino tinto",
"product_description":"\u0026lt;!--\ntd {border: 1px solid #ccc;}br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}\n--\u003eRitual Pétalos de Rosas y Vino tinto, Exquisito masaje que ofrece bienestar, relajación e hidrata la piel. Realizamos el ritual con mascarilla hidratante y antioxidante, piedras calientes, y cuarzos para ofrecer un delicioso y aromático descanso a todo el cuerpo.",
"variant_title":"Obispado",
"variant_options":["Obispado"]
}
```

> Code

The calling code is:

```
jQuery.getJSON('/products/'+getProduct.product_handle+'.js', function(product) {

    product.variants.forEach(function(variant) {
      if (getProduct.sucursal == variant.title){
        jQuery.post('/cart/add.js', {
          quantity: 1,
          id: variant.id
        });
      }
    });

  });
```

> Platforms

I'm working with Shopify with the template language Liquid, inside this liquid I have a `<script>` tag that runs AJAX for calling a method from Shopify.

> More information

I know that the error it must have javascript syntax but like I said before I didn't see the error.

**Anyone knows about this error?**

I appreciate every answer.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for any of these endpoints you are requesting? All the docs i see end in .json, not .js.

Comment: Here they are: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api#shopify-ajax-api-reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the long-form of the `jquery.ajax` call to specify all the AJAX parameters manually:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url:'/cart/add.js',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { quantity:1, variant: variant.id }
  // Optional: success/error functions
})
```

Building on the other answers, it may be that jQuery is expecting one type of response header but is actually receiving a different type.

If this works, you should be able to go back to using `jQuery.post` by supplying a 4th parameter for the data type (`'json'`): https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Also to note: If your code is able to match multiple variants in the product, your code will run into problems - for multiple additions, you will want to make sure that the first cart-alteration (add/update/remove/etc) is complete before posting your next cart-alteration.

Comment: This solution works! I was just need to specify the dataType like you said!

Comment: Perfect!  Glad I was able to help!

Comment: Thanks for this, so weird that this is the correct answer. Why is Shopify's documentation wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to @dave-b's answer: a drop-in replacement for Shopify's documentation which gathers the form data via serialization is:

```
  jQuery.post({
    url:'/cart/add.js',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('form[action="/cart/add"]').serialize()
    success: function() {
      //
    },
    error: function() {
      //
    }
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

Your URLs end in `.js` which imply that the server is going to respond with a `Content-Type: application/javascript` header to tell the browser that it is sending JavaScript.

The data you are quoting is *not* JavaScript, it is JSON.

jQuery is attempting to execute the JSON as if it were JavaScript (because that is what the server said it should do with the data) and this is failing.

Make the server respond with the correct header for JSON data: `Content-Type: application/json`.

You can probably do this by replacing `.js` with `.json`.

Comment: @KevinB — The documentation says it is returning JSON. It is returning JSON. It just has a Content-Type header that claims it is returning JavaScript.

Comment: @KevinB - The documentation also says that all URLs end in .js and then shows one ending in .json. Try requesting .json and see what happens.